# How to validate if is a browser on the server side without window reference?

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm working on angular application that have SSR integration with angular universal. On this project we use a plug-in for some steppers (bs-stepper). The issue is that this plug-in have a multiple window reference like this:

```
var matches = window.Element.prototype.matches;
```

I need a way to validate that is a browser or not, a tried multiple options like "detect" and "navigator".

Comment: If you need to know if `window` exists or not, just check for `window`. That being said, node will always have a global variable named `process` that is *usually* not present in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `isPlatformBrowser`

**component.ts**

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

//...
private isBrowser: boolean;

constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
   this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
  }
}
```

You can also try using `domino` in `server.ts` for when you don't have control over where browser elements are used (e.g. when using 3rs party libraries)